# Wo ist die Grenze zwischen Jahreszahlen als "Tausend" und Jahreszahlen als "-hundert"?

Tags: numbers

So ist es bei mir: Ich lese *1800* als "*achzehnhundert*", aber *1100* als "*eintausend(und)einhundert*".
Irgendwo hört die typische Angabe von Jahreszahlen auf, sich gut anzuhören.
Ist das regional? Könnt ihr das Gefühl nachempfinden? Wenn ja, wo würdet ihr die Grenze setzen?

Meine Ansicht:

```
+------+----------------------------+
| Jahr |        Ausgesprochen       |
+------+----------------------------+
| 1000 | Eintausend                 |
| 1100 | Eintausend(und)einhundert  |
| 1200 | Eintausend(und)zweihundert |
| 1300 | Dreizehnhundert            |
| 1400 | Vierzehnhundert            |
|  ... |                            |
| 1900 | Neunzehnhundert            |
| 2000 | Zweitausend                |
| 2100 | Zweitausend(und)einhundert |
|  ... |                            |
+------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

Das scheint von Person zu Person und Fachrichtung zu Fachrichtung unterschiedlich zu sein. Da sich alle verstehen, mit ihren unterschiedlichen Aussprachen, schätze ich das es so etwas wie "richtig" diesbezüglich nicht gibt.

Das einzige, das ich noch nie gehört habe und wo ich spontan sagen würde "das ist falsch", ist ganze tausender als hunderter auszusprechen.

Also *Neun*hundert, *Elf*hundert, *Zwölf*hundert, *Neunzehn*hundert nach Christus.

Niemals *Zehn*hundert. Oder *Zwanzig*hundert. Das ist *Tausend* bzw. *Zweitausend*.

Das gilt allerdings nur, wenn man das Wort "hundert" auch ausspricht. Menschen die Elf-Dreiundfünfzig für 1153 n. Chr. sagen, die können auch ohne Probleme Zehn-Sechundsechzig für 1066 n. Chr. sagen, ohne das es sich komisch anhört.

Comment: Jahrhunderte über 20 funktionieren doch auch nicht? Sagt irgendjemand _Zweiundzwanzighundert_?

Comment: hm, ich muss zugeben, das ich selten mit Leuten über die weit entfernte Zukunft oder über Dinge vor der Antike rede, kann gut sein, das es da genauso ist.

Comment: Ich nehme an, dass sich die "...zehnhundert"-Variante wegen der effizienteren Aussprache (weniger Silben) durchgesetzt hat und damit als "eher richtig" wahrgenommen wird. Einundzwanzighundert und Zweitausendeinhundert haben hingegen die gleiche Anzahl von Silben. Da die Betonung im ersten Fall nur auf der ersten Silbe ist, man bei der zweiten Variante aber auch das "ein" von einhundert zumindest etwas betonen sollte, um es verständlich zu machen, wird sich vielleicht die erste Variante durchsetzen?

Comment: @Raketenolli Anders gedacht fängt "Zweitausend..." direkt mit "zwei" an, was viel eher die Zahl vermittelt. Und "elfhundert" hat für zwei Leute, die ich gefragt habe, nach ihrem Geschmack sogar zu wenige Silben gehabt. Verrückt das Ganze.

Comment: Schon, da es aber nur etwa zwei Jahrtausende gibt, über die man mit spezifischen Jahreszahlen spricht, hat das nur sehr wenig Informationsgehalt, und es ist effektiver, wenn man mit dem Jahrhundert anfängt. Wenn es nicht um Jahreszahlen geht, verteilen sich die Zahlen, die man ausspricht, ganz anders, und die meisten Leute sagen die Zahl dann hoffentlich "normal", also "Das E-Bike kostet eintausendneunhundertneunzig Euro", aber "Die Wiedervereinigung war Neunzehnhundertneunzig". Und ja, "Elfhundert" klingt komisch, ist aber wohl auch nur Gewöhnungssache

Answer (score 1):

Ich weiß nicht, wie andere das machen. Ich sage jedenfalls …

- … *-tausend-* zu den Tausendern, zum Beispiel

> 1048 = *Tausend-achtundvierzig*
>
> 2023 = *Zweitausend-dreiundzwanzig*
>
> 4001 = *Viertausend-eins*

- … *-hundert-* zu den Hundertern, zum Beispiel

> 1148 = *Elfhundert-achtundvierzig*
>
> 2223 = *Zweiundzwanzighundert-dreiundzwanzig*
>
> 4601 = Sechsundvierzighundert-eins*

Comment: Das ist verwunderlich

Answer (score 0):

Wenn es um eine Jahreszahl geht, spricht man Zahlen zwischen zwischen 1100 und 1999 als "...hundert":

> Im Jahr elfhundert.

Wenn es nicht um eine Jahreszahl geht, spricht man Zahlen über 999 als "...tausend":

> Eintausendneunhundertdreiundachzig Euro.

Das ist die verbreitete Konvention, und so hört man es von professionellen Sprechern (beispielsweise in den Nachrichten).

Ich habe noch nie gehört, dass jemand "neunzehnhundertdreiundachzig Euro" sagt. Gelegentlich hört man im informellen Sprachgebrauch jedoch "elfhundert Euro" *bei ganzen Hundertern zwischen 1100 und 1500*. Bei höheren Zahlen (1800 Euro) ist mir das noch nie begegnet. Meiner Beobachtung und meinem Sprachgefühl nach liegt die Grenze bei 1500 – das hört man noch als "fünfzehnhundert Euro", "sechzehnhundert Euro" hört man aber schon nicht mehr (oder äußerst selten).